# Password checker error - python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple password checker in Python. It should accept a password if it has more than 1 upper and lower case letter and if it is more than 8 characters long. But when I run this I get the "do not continue" option from the `if` statement. Is there something wrong with the `if` statement?

```
passwd1 = input("enter your password>>>")
passwd2 = input("re-enter your password>>>")

lower=0
upper=0
for i in passwd1:
    if(i.islower()):
        lower=lower+1
    elif(i.isupper()):
        upper=upper+1

if lower + upper >= 8 and lower<0 and upper<0 and passwd1 == passwd2:
    print("continue")
else:
    print("do not continue")
```

Thanks

Comment: Please ensure that you are using the correct indentation for your script. For example, the indentation on the conditional inside the loop is not consistent between the `if` and `else` branches.

Comment: How could `lower<0`, for example, ever be true? Given that you start at `lower=0` and only ever increase it, that seems... unlikely.

Comment: @clemens - you modified the indentation of the code block - this might have been the issue that the OP was dealing with - in the future, please refrain from making edits from code blocks without first verifying that it was indeed the OPs intention.

Comment: @Lix: No, I din't change the indentation depth. This shouln't be the error. There are some other errors, like `lower + upper >= 8`.

Comment: @clemens - the edit history shows that your modifications did alter the indentation - http://i.imgur.com/flxHj12.png. I am aware that in this case it is probably not the main issue, but even still, modifying the supplied code is problematic.

Comment: @Lix: I didn't say I didn't change the indentation. I just said that it didn't change the semantics of the program. In this program you can't change the indentation of the for-loop, which is changing the semantics without producing an error because every block contains just a single statement.

Comment: BTW, this code does _not_ test that the password has a length greater than 8.

Comment: The condition must be "lower>0 and upper>0".

Answer (score 0):

you will always go to the `else` block because this condition `and lower<0 and upper<0` will never be met ,since you initiate lower,upper to 0 and only increase them in you if : `lower=lower+1` , `upper=upper+1` , 
and why do you need this condition anyway??? i don't see the purpose of this condition , remove this condition `and lower<0 and upper<0` and it will work!